# Was Louis stalked days in advance too?

Tags: ghostbusters

So, we know why Dana and Louis act so [differently](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22300/why-do-dana-and-tully-act-so-differently), but that leads me to ask, was Louis Tully ever stalked in the same way Dana was? Perhaps not having Zool fry his eggs for him, but was there a little more investigation prior to possession?

I know this information isn't in the first film, but is it ever mentioned in interviews, comments try, novelisations etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the the [Wiki page](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Louis_Tully) the dogs were looking for a host and found Louis at a party, cornered and possessed him.  So it would appear he was not stalked.

Comment: If by 'cornered and possessed' you mean "Chased through downtown Manhattan, despite many other people being in the vicinity," yes.

Answer (score 5):

In a word, yes. The [Richard Mueller](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Richard_Mueller) novelisation of the film states that the 'Terror Dog' was specifically looking for Louis and that while it was aware of his shortcomings, he was **its sole target**

> The terror-dog had made its way down the side of the building and
>   stepped through the bedroom window, shedding glass and broken mullions
>   like flies off armor plate. **The quarry was close, the one with whom
>   the great transformational joining would be resolved.** It was here,
>   within this very area, but not within this chamber itself. It sniffed
>   a few coats on the bed, then sprang to alertness as Louis Tully opened
>   the door. **It is him, the guardian thought,** but before it could
>   act, Louis tossed the coats over it and left, slamming the door behind
>   him. **It is nearsighted, decided the guardian, shaking off the coats.
>   It is ugly, too, but I have my duty. It let loose a terrible roar.**

Presumably he (like Dana) has been *prepared* for demonic possession by being in the vicinity of so much psychic energy. That would also explain why he's been buying headache tablets by the gross.

> *“I have acetylsalicylic acid but I get the generic from Walgreen’s
>   cause **I can get six hundred tablets for thirty-five percent less than
>   the cost of three hundred of the name brand.** Do you have a headache?”*

Comment: He's an accountant, so cost analysis isn't anything out of the norm but, 'Do you [also] have a headache?' lends credit to your theory.

Comment: @Mazura - The only people I've ever met who buy their headache tablets *hundreds at a time* are those with painful and persistent headaches.